# Flutter: Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'. Container(child: Row(children: [ ^^^^^^^^^

Tags: flutter

```
child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
             children: [
            CircleAvatar( 
               radius: 100,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/maria.jpeg'),
               ),
              Text('Maria Teresa',
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35,
               fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                color: Colors.yellow,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              Text('She is an actress only',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
               ),
               Container(child: Row(children: [],),)
              ],
            ),
```

I'm watching flutter tutorials, and doing the same from video but I get the error when add a

```
Container(child: Row(children:[],),)
```

Why I get this error?

In the video there is no error

Comment: That's not an error. Rather it's a suggestion/warning.

Comment: Explain more because its like primary question , follow guidelines

Comment: Best way to learn refer documentation, I think others will be agreed with me. Also by use video tutorial its not bad but dont copy there codes, use it understanding the theories

Answer (score 1):

`Container(child: Row(children: [],),)` is same as  `const Row(children: [],),)`

const objects are compile time constants and only one copy of them is made in memory. That is what the suggestion means.